# How to turn on PAE

Tags: windows-8.1, pae

How do I turn on PAE on my windows 8.1 computer. I don't need a lecture about what it is, I just need to know how to turn it on so I can run Kali Linux from a virtual box. One is installed om my computer the other is on a USB.

Comment: A quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=PAE+on+windows+8.1) lead me to [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/override-the-4gb-memory-barrier-on-32-bit-windows-81-systems/) post, that seems to depict a near step-by-step procedure.

Comment: I already tried that. It didn't work on my computer.

Comment: So continue from there. Were you unable to perform a step on the procedure? What else have you tried? Also, you should edit your post and add your computer specs; something regarding your computer may prevent you from enabling PAE.

Comment: What specs would you like?

Answer (score 3):

[Windows 8 and 8.1 already use PAE all the time.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn482072.aspx) It doesn't even run on CPUs which don't support PAE.

So you don't need to change anything. When you looking for using more than 4GB of RAM in a 32Bit Windows, try [this bootloader](http://www.itsec.it/download/BootkitInstaller.zip).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### ~10 years later:

As per Microsoft Docs, Microsoft indeed [required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-8.1-and-8/dn482072(v=win.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) PAE-capable hardware for Windows 8.1 32-bit, but it seems that requirement was actually motivated by enforcing NX (No-Execute) capability that requires PAE being enabled. As documented at Physical Memory Limits for Windows Releases [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-limits-for-windows-releases#physical-memory-limits-windows-8), the RAM limit for Windows 8.1 is 4 GB (as well as for Windows 7), with the note in the last section of the article page:

> X86 client versions of Windows don’t support physical memory above the 4GB mark, so they can’t access these remapped regions. Any X64 Windows or X86 Server release can.

Enabling PAE by using corresponding switch in *bcdedit* explicitly (as explained at the Microsoft Docs [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/physical-address-extension#enabling-pae) dedicated to PAE technology) did not increase system memory limit in my lab with Windows 8.1 32-bit.

So it seems there's no *official* way to enable PAE on Windows 8.1 32-bit.

Please correct me if I'm mistaken or have missed something important on the matter. Comments are appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Windows 8 does not support PAE. Microsoft has removed this option from windows 7 and later.

There are a few hacks on the net which involve patching your windows binaries with executables downloaded from a third party source. I have obviously not tested these on any important system.

The real question though is, why not install windows 8 64 bit?  Using a cripled (memory wise) system and trying to patch it to work around its limitations can work, but the same CoA which activated the 32 bit installation of windows 8 should also work on a 64 bit version.

Comment: one reason might be driver support on antiquated machines